# Calculation of a SUMPRODUCT array formula

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have written the following SUMPRODUCT array formula;

```
{=SUMPRODUCT((A2=ExportedStudyView[[ ID]])*(E2=ExportedStudyView[[ TYPE]])*(F2=ExportedStudyView[Study_Date])*(ExportedStudyView [ Duration(h:m:s)] ))}
```

The formula works quite nicely, however I would like to have the values calculated and entered via a VBA script to avoid any user error that could break the array.

I've searched a through the questions and answers here and on other sites, but I can't seem to find anything that addresses this type of array to VBA.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: That formula does not require committing with CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER.